# What was the armadillo/canine hybrid in "Noah"?

Tags: noah

The 2014 film *Noah* (starring Russell Crowe) seemed to contain a number of very unusual animals.

What was the armadillo/canine hybrid thing?

[image: Brown creature looking like the offspring of an armadillo and a dog]

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit on [Movies&TV.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com), since it is about a movie, but not a work of Speculative Fiction.

Comment: @SQB - If you relate it to the source material, especially the graphic novel, it's pretty clear that Noah (2014) is a work of science fiction. The director notes that it contains "fantastical" elements.

Comment: Also, the existing consensus on meta is that Noah (2014) is on topic.

Comment: [Related meta discussion.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/how-will-the-upcoming-noah-film-be-handled)

Comment: I apologise for my earlier comment about the work being off-topic. Not having seen _Noah_, I assumed it to be about 'just' the biblical story. And you know what they say about assumptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They were, erm, "tweaked" according to the film's director Darren Aronofsky. His intent seems to have been to avoid the "cliché" of using real, recognisable animals.

In an [interview](https://www.dga.org/Craft/DGAQ/All-Articles/1304-Fall-2013/Darren-Aronofsky.aspx) for the Digital Guild of America he described them thusly;

> We had to create an entire animal kingdom. **All the animals in the
> movie are slightly tweaked;** I didn’t want the clichéd polar bear,
> elephant, and lion walking onto the Ark; I didn’t want the shot of a
> giraffe’s head looking over the rail. I wanted to respect the
> storyline and think what would have been involved if it all really
> happened.
>
> “In collaboration with Industrial Light & Magic (ILM)], we basically
> went through the animal kingdom and pinpointed the body types we
> wanted: some pachyderms, some rodents, reptiles, and the bird kingdom.
> We chose the species and they were brought to life with different furs
> and colors. **We didn’t want anything fully recognizable but not
> completely absurd either.**
>
> "There's all these creatures that you're not expecting to see ... we were able to create ***our own*** animal kingdom"

In the [draft script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Noah.pdf) and graphic novel, the animal was another fictional creature referred to as a "single-horned bison" whose horn the men were attempting to cut off. Although the animal has obviously changed, much of the dialogue has remained.

[image: comic panel of the one-horned bison killed by spears]